# How to keep current zoom scale and translate level when re-rendering graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, graph, dagre-d3

I have a d3 graph that allows for pan and zoom behavior. It also has subGraph functionality that allows a user to expand and collapse the subGraph. When the user clicks on the icon to open and close the subGraph this code runs:

```
btn.on("click", function(d:any, i:any) {
        parentNode = nodeObject; // gives me he x and y coordinates of the parent node
        d3.event["stopPropagation"]();
        e["subGraph"].expand = !expand; // add or remove subGraph

        window.resetGraph = !window.resetGraph;
        console.log(window.resetGraph);
        if (window.resetGraph) {
                window.scale = window.zoom.scale();
                window.translate  = window.zoom.translate();
                window.zoom.scale(1).translate([0 , 0]);
        } else {    
                                     window.zoom.scale(window.scale).translate(window.translate);
         }

         console.log(window.zoom.scale());
         console.log(translate);    

        renderGraph();
});
```

I'm essentially adding and removing the subGraph property of the node on click of the icon. Then redrawing the graph completely.

I can get the x and y coordinates of the parent container, but if I am re-rendering the graph, how can I go about rendering the graph so that the graph stays at the same scale and translation as it was when I clicked on the toggle subGraph icon. I am trying to redraw the graph at the same position as it was before just with the subGraph either expanded or collapsed. Below is the code that seems to be fighting me when the graph renders:

```
   var scaleGraph = function() {
                var graphWidth = g.graph().width + 4;
                var graphHeight = g.graph().height + 4;
                var width = parseInt(svg.style("width").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
                var height = parseInt(svg.style("height").replace(/px/, ""), 10);
                var zoomScale = originalZoomScale;
                // Zoom and scale to fit        
                if (ctrl.autoResizeGraph === "original") {
                    zoomScale = initialZoomScale;
                }


                translate = [(width / 2) - ((graphWidth * zoomScale) / 2) + 2, 1];

                zoom.center([width / 2, height / 2]);
                zoom.size([width, height]);

                zoom.translate(translate);
                zoom.scale(zoomScale);

                zoom.event(svg);
            };
```

If I check if the toggle Icon has been clicked, can I redraw the graph with the same scale and translation as before it was redrawn?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it by keeping track of the current scale and translation values:

```
  zoom.on("zoom", function() {
        svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + (<any>d3.event).translate + ")" + "scale(" + (<any>d3.event).scale + ")");  

      // keep track of the currentZoomScale and currentPosition at all times
        currentZoomScale = (<any>d3.event).scale;
        currentPosition = (<any>d3.event).translate;

  });
```

Then when re-rendering the graph in my scaleGraph function above I just checked to see if the graph was re-rendered because of the subGraph being toggled, if it has then I use the current scale and translation values:

```
  if (ctrl.autoResizeGraph !== "original" && togglingSubGraph) {
            zoomScale = currentZoomScale; // render the graph at its current scale
            translate = currentPosition; // render the graph at its current position

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created one fiddle for you.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/passionintellectual/sp844e5p/)

Please check the function refreshGraph

```
  var refreshGraph =function(){
    window.resetGraph = !window.resetGraph;
  console.log(window.resetGraph);
  if(window.resetGraph){ 
    window.scale = window.zoom.scale();
    window.translate  = window.zoom.translate();

    window.zoom.scale(1).translate([0,0]);
  }else{
    window.zoom.scale(window.scale)
    .translate(window.translate);
  }
    console.log(window.zoom.scale());

  console.log(translate);

  draw();
}
```

I have used window.zoom (used window to let you know that this is shared)

Button reset toggles the zoom level to 0 scale and toggles back to where it was if clicked again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, just to make sure I'm understanding correctly that window.zoom keeps track of the current scale and translate and will hold that as the graph re-renders? Because I do need to re-draw the graph with the updated node with the subGraph either expanded or collapsed. I updated my initial post with what I want to make work.. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, window variables keeps track of the current scale. When you share the zoom object the scales are automatically updated to reflect the zoom coordinates. So when you re render it should work. I am also calling draw method again in above fiddle. Please mark as answer if it works.

Comment: Will definitely mark as answer if it works out.  I updated my post. I am clicking on the toggle icon which which will expand or collapse the graph, then getting the window variables and re-rendering the entire graph. Can I still call the scaleGraph function with this approach or should I not have to? Do the window variables override the zoom methods I am calling in scaleGraph? Thanks

Comment: I don't see this working for me. I'm not sure I understand what that function is doing.

Comment: When you call the methods scale on window.zoom, it actually changes your d3 scale object and with this modified d3scales, you need to rerender the graph . so you get the graph zoomed to the scale you want. you should share the scales in zoom function and the graph rendering. In the fiddle if you click the reset button twice, on first time, it resets to 0 scale (i.e. no zoom) and second time, it restores the zoom.  You zoom the graph in the fiddle, then click multiple times on reset button.

Comment: I only want this line then, window.zoom.scale(window.scale)
    .translate(window.translate); and I get errors saying zoom and translate do not exist on the window